# Can you create deep copy of nested lists through use of it's constructor?

Tags: c#, list, deep-copy

I know you can give a list object as parameter of list constructor to **copy** 1 list to the other.

By doing so, you can create a **deep copy** if used types are simple build-in once (**which precisely?**). For example of type *string*:

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>();

List<string> testListCopy = new List<string>(testList );
```

Can you create a **deep copy** if you work with nested Lists? :

```
List<List<string>> testList = new List<List<string>>();

List<List<string>> testListCopy = new List<List<string>>(testList );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `List<T>` constructor won't do this for you, but you can do it yourself with:

```
List<List<string>> testList = new List<List<string>>();
List<List<string>> testListCopy = new List<List<string>>(testList.Select(x => x.ToList()));
```

Or even this, which is equivalent:

```
List<List<string>> testListCopy = testList.Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A copy is not just shallow or deep.  It's a scale with multiple values along it with a "most deep" and "most shallow" option.  Just using a list's copy constructor results in a copy that's somewhere in the middle; it is not a "deep copy".

What you're doing is re-creating a new list, without copying a reference to it, but you're performing a shallow copy on the items in that list.  If the items in that inner list are themselves lists, or other mutable reference types, you'd need to do a deep copy of them, and of all of their referenced fields, etc. all the way down the chain.  That would be a truly "deep" copy.  Doing so is non-trivial, and impossible in the general case.  There is no truly effective way to write an implementation for `public static T DeepCopy<T>(T object)` that would work for any type.  (You can get close by trying to leverage serialization, but not all objects can be serialized).

As to the specific case of a `List<List<string>>`, you simply need to create a new outer list, as well as new lists for each of the inner lists.  P.s.w.g has given a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068713/1159478) to this particular problem:

```
List<List<string>> listCopy = list.Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```