# How to copy values from nested list into new list

Tags: c#

I have a nested list that contains

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

The list can be used like:

```
var Persons = new List<Person>();
Persons.Add(new Person("Eric"));
Persons[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Tom"));
Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("John"));
Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Bill"));
Persons.Add(new Person("John");
```

Now I have this class:

```
public class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<Human> SubHuman { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say the Persons list was created. How can I now create a new list `Humans` out of the Persons list (iterate over the list) whereas the name of each Human is the name of the appropriate Person? It should also be nested like Persons and all Humans should have age 12.

Comment: So a `Child` corresponds a `SubHuman` ? How deep is your list of children nested? Allways 3 levels (person-->child-->child) or is the number of generations arbitrary?

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068713/9020340

Comment: @HimBromBeere The number of Levels is not fixed. It could be 1000 levels. I want a list `Humans` that is nested like `Persons` and cointains the `Name`of `Persons`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static List<Human> Convert(List<Person> persons)
{
    List<Human> humans = new List<Human>();
    foreach (Person p in persons)
    {
        Human newHuman = new Human(p.Name, 12);
        if (p.Childs != null)
        {
            newHuman.SubHuman = convert(p.Childs);
        }
        humans.Add(newHuman);
    }
    return humans;
}
```

I also added a constructor in `Human` class.

```
class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<Human> SubHuman { get; set; }

    public Human(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Use it like this, in your example:

```
var Humans = Convert(Persons);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, Human and Person have just common Properties... I only see a "manual" way to map one class instance to another.

Expecting that the SubHuman, resp. Children may be very deep, I've chose a recursive solution.

here an example:

```
    static Human Convert(Person p)
    {
        var result = new Human() { Name = p.Name, Age = 12 };
        if (p.Childs?.Any() == true)
        {
            result.SubHuman = new List<Human>();
            p.Childs.ForEach(x => result.SubHuman.Add(Convert(x))); //Recursion here
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This could be called with:

```
 List<Human> humans = Persons.Select(x => Convert(x)).ToList();
```

EDIT: I thing this is not a sustainable approach. Depending on the putpose to do this, I'd recommend to make common interface an/or inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping one entity to another entity, and since you have a tree structure there / nesting, which is potentially unlimited, you can use recursion but only with caution - a truly infinite nesting would lead to a stack overflow in my opinion.

Given this sample list:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
  new Person("Tom")
  {
    Childs = new List<Person> {
        new Person("Maria"),
        new Person("Jonathan") {
            Childs = new List<Person> {
                new Person("Frank")
            }
        }
    }
  },
  new Person("Ila")
};
```

And this local function:

```
Human Extract(Person guy) 
{
    return new Human { Name = guy.Name, Age = 12, SubHuman = guy.Childs?.Select(Extract).ToList() ?? new List<Human>() };
}
```

You can then map the original list with a single expression:

```
List<Human> humans = people.Select(Extract).ToList();
```

Comment: It is not really infinite. I tried to make clear that the level of nested elements could not be predicted.